# cant use remove Event Listener

Tags: javascript

```
function attachEvent(element, event, callbackFunction) {
  if(element.addEventListener)  {
    element.addEventListener(event, function(){
      removeArray();
      callbackFunction(this.getAttribute("src"));
    }, false);
  }
}


function removeEvent(){
  var element = document.querySelectorAll('.Dicon');
  element.removeEventListener("click", handler);
  console.log("remove");
}
```

i have a few image which the class call **Dicon** ,and i use addEventlistner give them ability to click on , but now i wanna to remove the eventlistner, but somehow i cant make it work , i got error.

error

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.removeEventListener is not a function
```

how do i fix this problem ? they are all image.

Answer (score 3):

`querySelectorAll` returns a *collection*, not a single element. If you want to get only the first matching element, use `querySelector` (no `All`). Otherwise, you index into the collection (e.g., `[0]` for the first matching element, `[1]` for the second), using `length` to know how many there were.

You'll also need to define `handler`.

Note that you **can't** remove the handler you've attached using `addEventListener` in your first code block, because to remove a handler, you have to provide the ***same*** function reference to `removeEventListener` as you gave to `addEventListener`, and you don't have that reference because you passed a function expression into `addEventListener` directly.

You'd need to keep that reference somewhere (e.g., a variable or property) in order to use it later to remove the handler.

Comment: @TJ, there is no way to remove the event listener if we are not keeping the reference ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: Nope. You have to destroy and replace the element. This is one of the things that makes me continue to use jQuery: You can remove all handlers, or all handlers with a given "namespace", etc. It's possible because jQuery only hooks a given event on a given element **once**, and then it uses its own list of handlers to dispatch that event to our code. No way to do it with the native DOM methods.

Comment: @RayonDabre: That's right. jQuery attaches a single handler (its own) and keeps the handlers we give it in its own array. When the event occurs, it loops through its array, calling the handlers. This is also why back in the day it was able to make the handlers get called in the order defined by DOM2, even on old Microsoft browsers using `attachEvent` which (it just so happened) called them in the opposite order.

Comment: Thank for your time! You are a complete _reference material_ :)

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a htmlCollection, so you need to loop through the items to remove the listener from each item:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.Dicon');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(element, function(el) {
    el.removeEventListener("click", handler);
});
```

Also note what [@T.J. Crowder states in his answer's](http://[cant%20use%20remove%20Event%20Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644410/3993662)) second block about removing handlers for the exact same function reference.

Comment: the function work, but somehow the onclick are not removing.

Comment: See @T.J.Crowder's explanation!

Comment: why do you have to use `Array.prototype` instead of for loop?